# Change url onclick without javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, button, onclick

How can I change url location in same window onlick without script for this button:

```
<button type="submit" name="select" value="true" onclick="window.open('/newurl')" class="btn btn-default2 btn-block"><i class="fa fa-car"></i>Search</button>
```

Now it goes back 1, but instead I want it to go to some url.

EDIT: how can I do it with javascript instead?
HTML

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML in the question

Comment: Edited post with html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. changing the script

   `'onclick="location=\'somewhereelse.html\'; return false ', 'cancel');`
2. using a link

   `<a href="somewhereelse.html" class="styledlikeabutton">Cancel</a>`
3. Best solution if you need to submit the form: redirect from server using a redirect header

Comment: Button is used for a function, so I want something as 1. but that doesn't work. It just not go anywhere.

Comment: Please show what is rendered instead of PHP -and what function. Instead add your code to the function if possible

Comment: `<button type="submit" name="select" value="true" onclick="location='/newurl'" class="btn btn-default2 btn-block"><i class="fa fa-car"></i>Search</button>`

Comment: it works with`'onclick="window.open(\'<url>\')"'` but I dont want it to open new windows. If I add _self again it's not redirecting to new url.

Comment: Return false. It's a submit button or change to type=button

Comment: Can you explain?

Comment: Your button is not a button - it submits the form it's in. So you need to not submit

Comment: Ok, sorry for not being clear. I need to submit form and change link. I'm new to this. Thank you for your help. If i add return false, it only changes link, but without sumbiting form.

Comment: Redirect from server - best solution

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use **window.open**  in your button text.

```
'onclick="window.open(\'<url>\')"'
```

Comment: That works, but it opens new window. If I add "_self", it doesn't change url.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='your_link_here.html'">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.href` returns the href (URL) of the current page (_self).